# How to exclude specific folders from TextMate 2 file browser using .tm_properties

Tags: textmate, textmate2

I'm using a `.tm_properties` file to exclude certain folders from the file browser of a TextMate 2 project, and it's generally working great. So, for instance, I've got a line like this to exclude a `junk` folder:

`excludeDirectories = "{$excludeDirectories,junk}"`

And, that works great to hide all folders called `junk`.

**BUT**, let's say I happen to have two folders in the project that are both called `junk`, and I want to exclude one but include the other. How do I set the first junk folder specifically to be excluded, while not excluding the second?

I've tried stuff like this, with no success:

`excludeDirectories = "{$excludeDirectories,/junk}"`

`excludeDirectories = "{$excludeDirectories,~/junk}"`

`excludeDirectories = "{$excludeDirectories,./junk}"`

`excludeDirectories = "{$excludeDirectories,'./junk'}"`

Anyone know if this is possible and/or how to accomplish? Thx!

Comment: Is this a single .tm_properties file, or could you simply make each folder have a .tm_properties excluding its child

Comment: @GrahamPHeath That's a good thought, but unfortunately didn't work. Looks like you're only meant to have one .tm_properties file per project.

Comment: You could try asking in the mailing list. http://lists.macromates.com/listinfo/textmate

Comment: I posted a similar question in this https://gist.github.com/dvessel/1478685

Comment: @Wolfr—ooh, great. Yeah, would still be interested in the answer to this. Definitely come back and let us know if you find out anything. Thx!